# Как передать значение переменных одного пользователя другому php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Я новичек в php, не судите строго) У меня есть игра на двоих, сделанная на js, с помощью ajax я в php файл получаю нужные мне переменные из js, и мне нужно отправить эти переменные другому пользователю, а у него они должны "распаковаться" и подставить свои значения его переменным. Обыскал кучу источников, но не нашел( 
Как реализовать передачу значений переменных между пользователями?
Надеюсь понятно объяснил)))

Comment: Покажите, что у вас из кода написано. Телепатов здесь нет

Comment: session_start(); $_SESSION['data1']=$data;  и на втором принять сессию

Comment: Самое простое - использовать что-то вроде https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/.
Т.е. это JSON-подобная бд с возможностями подключение к ней по сокету.
Можно передавать переменные между юзерами вообще без ajax-запросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Данный способ не является стопроцентно верным решением (более того, его можно и костылем назвать), это просто пример того, как можно реализовать передачу данных между пользователями посредством базы данных MySQL и PHP**

На будущее, такие вещи лучше делать на NodeJS.
Для PHP есть несколько решений, к примеру, сохранять полученные переменные в базу данных, а после считывать их на стороне второго пользователя.

Код для сервера:

```
<?php
# Устанавливаем заголовки
cors();

# Подключаемся к базе данных
$connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'database');
if(!$connect) exit;

# Сохраняем наши переменные в базе данных
if(isset($_POST['uid']) and isset($_POST['vars'])){
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $vars = $_POST['vars'];

    # Проверяем, есть ли запись о пользователе в базе данных, если нет, то создаем ее
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `vars_table` WHERE `uid`='$uid';");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0)
        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `vars_table`(`uid`, `variables`) VALUES ('$uid', '$vars')");
    else
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `vars_table` SET `variables`='$vars' WHERE `uid`='$uid';");

    # Отправляем назад ответ
    exit(
        json_encode(array('status' => true))
    );
}

# Получаем переменные из базы данных по уникальному ключу
if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];

    # Получаем из базы данных наши паременные
    $vars = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `variables` FROM `vars_table` WHERE `uid`='$uid';");

    # Проверяем, нашлась ли строка с нужным нам uid
    if(mysqli_num_rows($vars) == 0)
        exit(
            json_encode(array('status' => false))
        );

    # Отправляем назад ответ
    exit(
        json_encode(array(
            'status' => true,
            'variables' => mysqli_fetch_assoc($vars)
        ))
    );
}

function cors() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    }
}

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Остается только добавить играм уникальный идентификатор (UID), который будут знать оба пользователя, и при помощи JS общаться с сервером. Только не забудьте заменить данные для подключения, имена таблиц и колонок на свои.

```
// Отправляем переменные на сервер
const uid = '19A83658342C725D';
let post = {
    'uid': uid,
    'vars': JSON.stringify({
        var1: 'value1'
    })
};

let body = new FormData;
for(let variable in post) body.append(variable, post[variable]);

fetch('http://localhost/server.php', {
    method: 'post',
    mode: 'cors',
    body: body
}).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(result => {
    // Получили ответ от сервера, если true, то, неожиданно, переменные сохранены в БД
    console.log(result);
});
```

Для второго (получающего) пользователя:

```
const uid = '19A83658342C725D';
fetch(`http://localhost/server.php?uid=${uid}`).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);

    // Переменные от первого пользователя
    console.log(
        JSON.parse(result.variables.variables)
    );
});
```

*P.S.: Такой способ подойдет для игры по типу шахмат, т.е. без каких-либо активных действий, для более динамичный игр используются совершенно другие технологии*

**Документация по MySQL Improved:**
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Я треть твоего кода не понимаю( я еще это не учил. Можешь немного подробнее описать))) напиши мне в вк https://vk.com/vlad_rogov2000

Answer (score 0):

Для этих целей используются базы данных или кэш.
Если данные предполагается хранить короткое время и они не представляют большой важности, но при этом их надо быстро и часто получать/сохранять твой выбор кэш (redis, memcached).
Ну или найти какой нибудь файловый кэшь, на пример https://packagist.org/packages/phpfastcache/phpfastcache